# Selective file download in AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have files in S3 bucket. I was trying to download files based on a date, like 08th aug, 09th Aug etc.

I used the following code, but it still downloads the entire bucket:

```bash
aws s3 cp s3://bucketname/ folder/file \
    --profile pname \
    --exclude \"*\" \
    --recursive \
    --include \"" + "2015-08-09" + "*\"
```

I am not sure, how to achieve this. How can I download selective date file?

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? Is the date encoded in your filename, or do you wish to base the download on the creation date of the object?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Filename are '2015-08-15T001Z.log.gz',  '2015-08-14T001Z.log.gz', etc. For each day, there will be 24 files ranging from 'T001z.log.gz to T023z.log.gz'.    I am looking for way to pick file of particular day for eg: 2015-08-15 which should copy all 24files of this date from S3 to local machine.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

This command will copy all files starting with `2015-08-15`:

```
aws s3 cp s3://BUCKET/ folder --exclude "*" --include "2015-08-15*" --recursive
```

If your goal is to synchronize a set of files without copying them twice, use the `sync` command:

```
aws s3 sync s3://BUCKET/ folder
```

That will copy all files that have been added or modified since the previous sync.

In fact, this is the equivalent of the above `cp` command:

```
aws s3 sync s3://BUCKET/ folder --exclude "*" --include "2015-08-15*"
```

References:

- [AWS CLI `s3 sync` command documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html)
- [AWS CLI `s3 cp` command documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html)

Comment: It takes hours to download logs for the last day when a folder contains logs for several years, because `aws s3 sync ` iterates by all of them and compare with `exclude`/`include` filters. Is there any way to do it faster?

Answer (score 3):

### Bash Command to copy all files for specific date or month to current folder

```
aws s3 ls s3://bucketname/ | grep '2021-02' | awk '{print $4}' | aws s3 cp s3://bucketname/{} folder
```

**Command is doing the following thing**

1. Listing all the files under a bucket
2. Filtering out all the files of 2021-02 i.e. all files of feb month of 2021
3. Filtering out only the name of them
4. running command `aws s3 cp` on specific files

Comment: Till step 3 it works, I am getting `fatal error: An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Key` in the 4th step, Do i need to pass the file names manually instead of {} ?

Comment: This is good, but the last bit needs to be changed to `xargs -I {} aws s3 cp s3://bucketname/{} folder` in order to work. The shell doesn't magically replace `{}` with whatever was passed from `stdin`, you need xargs.

Answer (score 1):

> In case your bucket size is large in the upwards of 10 to 20 gigs,
>   this was true in my own personal use case, you can achieve the same
>   goal by using `sync` in multiple terminal windows.

All the terminal sessions can use the same token, in case you need to generate a token for prod environment.

```
 $ aws s3 sync s3://bucket-name/sub-name/another-name folder-name-in-pwd/
 --exclude "*" --include "name_date1*"  --profile UR_AC_SomeName
```

and another terminal window (same pwd)

```
$ aws s3 sync s3://bucket-name/sub-name/another-name folder-name-in-pwd/ 
    --exclude "*" --include "name_date2*"  --profile UR_AC_SomeName
```

and another two for `"name_date3*" and "name_date4*"`

> Additionally, you can also do multiple excludes in the same sync
>   command as in:

```
$ aws s3 sync s3://bucket-name/sub-name/another-name my-local-path/ 
--exclude="*.log/*" --exclude=img --exclude=".error" --exclude=tmp 
--exclude="*.cache"
```

Answer (score 0):

**This Bash Script will copy all files from one bucket to another by modified-date using aws-cli.**

```
aws s3 ls <BCKT_NAME> --recursive | sort | grep "2020-08-*" | cut -b 32- > a.txt
```

**Inside Bash File**

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    aws s3 cp s3://<SRC_BCKT>/${line} s3://<DEST_BCKT>/${line} --sse AES256
done < a.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

`aws` cli is really slow at this. I waited hours and nothing really happened. So I looked for alternatives.

https://github.com/peak/s5cmd worked great.

supports globs, for example:

```sh
s5cmd -numworkers 30 cp 's3://logs-bucket/2022-03-30-19-*' .
```

is really blazing fast, so you can work with buckets that have s3 access logs without much fuss.