# Download list of specific files from AWS S3 using CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface

I am trying to download only specific files from AWS. I have the list of file URLs. Using the CLI I can only download all files in a bucket using the --recursive command, but I only want to download the files in my list. Any ideas on how to do that?

Answer (score 7):

This is possibly a duplicate of:
[Selective file download in AWS S3 CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31942341/selective-file-download-in-aws-s3-cli)

You can do something along the lines of:

```
aws s3 cp s3://BUCKET/ folder --exclude "*" --include "2018-02-06*" --recursive
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html

Comment: Thank you Ryan. However, the user in that case has a common characteristic to all his files, they all had the same date. My files don't have that, they are simply a subset of the files in the bucket in S3 and I have their URLs.

Comment: You don't have to use the * attribute, you can specify the exact urls. and then use multiple --includes in your single AWS Statement. I would wrap it in a Shell or python script using boto3 to open your list, and create a single AWS S3 CP command and execute that using the --include for each url.

Comment: @Sara You could use multiple `--include` parameters, specifying one per file to download. However, I don't think it would necessarily be any faster than grabbing one at a time because this functionality requires the AWS CLI to first scan for existing files (to fit the wildcard capabilities), whereas copying a specific file would only need one API call.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using boto3 and looping over my list. The multiple --include was slower than that. Looping over the list using aws s3 cp was also slower.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the s3 urls already in a file (say `file.list`), like -

```
s3://bucket/file1
s3://bucket/file2
```

You could download all the files to your current working directory with a simple bash script -

```
while read -r line;do aws s3 cp "$line" .;done < test.list
```

Comment: This works and it's what I have been using so far. However, this means that the aws command, which establishes a connection etc, has to be executed for every line, which is slow. I was wondering if there was a quicker way to go about it

Answer (score 0):

you can use python boto3 script for this, you can download with the same file structure of S3 Bucket.

```html
import boto3
import botocore
import os

# Initialize the S3 client
aws_access_key_id = 'AWSACESSKEY'
aws_secret_access_key = 'AWSSECRETACESSKEY' 
s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key)

# List of image object keys you want to download
image_keys_to_download = [
"sta10/maths/chapter10.pdf",
"sta11/science/biology/chapter08.pdf",
"data/sta10/class11/scientists/pythagoras"
]

# Destination directory where the images will be downloaded
destination_base_directory = "~/s3-download-class"

# Loop through the list of image keys and download each image while preserving folder structure
for image_key in image_keys_to_download:
    try:
        # Extract the folder structure from the image key
        folder_structure = os.path.dirname(image_key)

        # Create the destination directory including the folder structure
        destination_directory = os.path.join(destination_base_directory, folder_structure)

        # Make sure the destination directory exists
        os.makedirs(destination_directory, exist_ok=True)

        # Get the object from S3 and save it locally while preserving folder structure
        local_file_path = os.path.join(destination_directory, os.path.basename(image_key))
        s3.download_file('class-10-data', image_key, local_file_path) #Add your S3 Bucket name here.
        print(f"Downloaded {image_key}")
    except botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError:
        print("AWS credentials not found. Make sure you have configured your credentials.")
    except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
        if e.response['Error']['Code'] == "404":
            print(f"Image {image_key} not found in the S3 bucket.")
        else:
            print(f"Error downloading {image_key}: {e}")

print("Download process completed.")
```

I Hope With This Python Script, you can download specific images with same folder structure.

Answer (score -3):

People, I found out a quicker way to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69018735

WARNING: "Please make sure you don't have an empty line at the end of your text file".

It worked here! :-)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31429940)