# How do I download files with AWS CLI based on a list?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line

I'm trying to download a subset of files from a public s3 bucket that contains millions of IRS files. I can download the entire repository with the command:

`aws s3 sync s3://irs-form-990/ ./`

But it takes way too long!

I know I should be using the --include / --exclude flags, but I don't know how to use them with a list of values. I have a csv that contains unique identifiers for all the files from 2017 that I'd like, but how do I use it in with AWS CLI? The list itself is half a million IDs long.

[image]

Help much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54559662/5354201 or this: https://gist.github.com/rpbaptist/d21276a6d110afbffff67aefc284eabd  The idea is to use a script to iterate over the filenames in your list and download them.  Not sure what the performance would be vs. using a regular filter and a single command, but it may be an option to investigate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bash script which can read all the filenames from a file filename.txt.
All you have to do is to convert those IDs in filenames.

```
#!/bin/bash  
set -e  
while read line  
do  
   aws s3 cp s3://bucket-name/$line dest-path/  
done <filename.txt
```

This question was asked before and the answer you can find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38021661/copy-multiple-files-from-s3-bucket)

Comment: This is my first time writing a bash script, and I'm a little confused.

What is "$line dest-path/ " suppose to be? Is it suppose to be the location of filename.txt?

I also got the error " does not existerror occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Key "20161239.xml". If that means that particular file doesn't exist, is there a way to skip it and try the next one?

Comment: I have answered to your question, and this is the right way to do it. About how to write a bash script, what is a loop, what is a variable or to understand that "dest-path" is the path where your files should be copied, you will need to do some research by yourself.

Comment: Okay well it doesn't work even when I set the dest-path as the place I'd like them copied, so there's no need to be rude.